# how can a subclass use the superclass's comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

There is a comparator in the super class named 'comparator'.
In the subclass, I would like to compare two objects of it, how can I use the super class's comparator to compare them?

This statement is in the super class(it has been initialized in the constructor of the subclass):

```
    final Comparator<Node> comparator;
```

This function is in the subclass:

```
 /**
 * judge wheter pq[i] is less than pq[j]
 * @param i
 * @param j
 * @return true if pq[i] is less than pq[j]
 */
private boolean less(int i, int j) {

}
```

I would like to compare pq[i] and pq[j] in the function named 'less' using the comparator, so how can I do it?

Comment: If `pq` is an array of `Node`s, then you can use the comparator just like you use any other comparator. The fact that it is in the superclass doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, can you show me the example? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, the pq is an array of Node.

Comment: `comparator.compare(pq[i], pq[j]) < 0` assuming that `comparator` is visible to the subclass

Comment: inheritance rules, doesn't it? if it really is a subclass, it inherits the instance members of the parent class

Comment: sorry, the comparator is not visbble to the subclass, the class node is neither a parent class nor a child class. and the child class is a priority queue I would like to implement

Comment: but the idea said this: 'comparator' is not public in 'core.solver.heuristic.AbstractFrontier'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: @MakeItPossible then how is it a subclass? your question is "how can a subclass use the superclass comparator",and now you say there is no sub- and no parent class?

Comment: no no no, I mean that the class node is neither the parent class nor the child class, the child class is a priority queue I need to implement

Comment: @Stultuske but the child class can not use a private member of its parent class, and I can not modify the parent class

Comment: @MakeItPossible seeing as you provide 0 code of the parent class, how are we to know there are no methods through which the subclass can use it? Also, in your example, it is a final member, not a private member, which makes it usable in the subclass. It would be best if you actually showed your actual code, not something that 'may look a bit' like it.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see a problem with using a `Comparator`, defined on the superclass, for the subclass. Given below is a simple demo (**Note:** not following best practices).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class A {
    int x;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "x=" + x;
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator<A> comp = (a1, a2) -> Integer.compare(a1.x, a2.x);
        
        B b1 = new B(); b1.x = 10;
        B b2 = new B(); b2.x = 5;
        B b3 = new B(); b3.x = 15;
        List<B> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(b1, b2, b3));
        
        list.sort(comp);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[x=5, x=10, x=15]
```

### Update:

Thanks to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66981075/how-can-a-subclass-use-the-superclasss-comparator/66981239?noredirect=1#comment118533325_66981239)

You can replace `Comparator<A> comp = (a1, a2) -> Integer.compare(a1.x, a2.x)` with `Comparator<A> comp = Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.x)`.

Comment: but the idea said this: 'comparator' is not public in 'core.solver.heuristic.AbstractFrontier'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: Upvoted. I would use `(a1, a2) -> Integer.compare(a1.x, a2.x)` to emphasize that comparator is referring to `A` superclass.

Comment: @MakeItPossible 'not public' doesn't automatically mean 'private'. In your code you've posted, it is 'protected', so it is accessible in the subclass

Comment: @dariosicily or `Comparator<A> comp = Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.x);`

Comment: @Holger Thank you for the reminder, I had completely forgotten it like when I use `Supplier<Integer>` instead of `IntSupplier` or  similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Comparator`'s `compare` method which returns a positive number when the first object is more, 0 when objects are equal, and a negative when the first object is less than the second one.

```java
    /**
     * judge wheter pq[i] is less than pq[j]
     * @param i
     * @param j
     * @return true if pq[i] is less than pq[j]
     */
    private boolean less(int i, int j) {
        return comparator.compare(pq[i], pq[j]) < 0;
    }
```

Comment: but the idea said this: 'comparator' is not public in 'core.solver.heuristic.AbstractFrontier'. Cannot be accessed from outside package